# Apache is listening on port 80 but cannot connect to website

Tags: centos7, apache2.4

I recently launched an ecs instance with centos 7.3.
I followed a guideline to install apache and configure ports(80 and 443).
I try to visit http://my_ip but it's not responding, it says i should check proxy and firewall
Below is the iptables, i could not figure what's wrong

`Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25141/httpd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1878/sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25141/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      30048/mysqld`

Answer (score 2):

1.stop firewall(systemctl stop firewalld.service),make your selinux equal disabled(vim /etc/sysconfig/selinux)
2.check your apache configure file and make sure your configuration allow your client to access.
3. check your apache access.log and error.log
you can try these method,and you would better paste the error page screenshot.

Comment: how do I check if Apache is allowing client access? Is it the directory block?

Comment: there is nothing in access log

Comment: check your httpd.conf to find "Require all granted" or "Require all denied" configuration.
there is nothing in access log : make sure firewall closed and selinux disabled